# Creating better image loaded check jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image

This is merely an idea I have and I would like to get some input from senior developers. 
**I am trying to stay away from imageloaded plugins or any more " expensive" image load check.**

I am creating a lightweight  responsive slider plugin that on load checks the slide next div/image/media for height in order to 
instantiate slide height;

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div>
     anything...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <img src="....." />
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <video ..../>
  </div>


  <div class="slide">
    <embed..../>
  </div>   
</div>
```

So from above you can see that we want any media content.

Since we also want responsive slider ,  div.slider has no height on load but it gets the first slide height.

This works well if the slide does not contain an image. So to get a proper height of a slide that has an image I must do a check if there is image in a slide and wait for it.

```
loadSlides: function () {

    var self = this;
    var findImg = $(self.settings.container).find('img');
    var firstImg = $("<img />").attr("src", findImg.attr('src') + "?" + new Date().getTime());

    self.allslides.each(function (index, element) {

        if (findImg.length) {

            $(firstImg).load(function () {
                self.setHeights(element);
            });

        } else {

            self.setHeights(element);
        }

        $(element).eq(index).css({
            'z-index': 2,
            'opacity': 1
        });

    });

}
```

The code works fine but I cant shake this idea off.

In order to make sure all slides are loaded , would it be smart to add a 1x1px image at the end of the slider and check that one for load? This way we can avoid check for images or media inside slides
and just wait for our image to load. Like this

```
<div class="slider">
  --slide 
  -- slide


<img class="loadcheck" src="myloadcheck" />
```

**The question is would that last image indeed load very last after all slides are rendered no matter what their content is?**

Comment: nice idea, you should try it out !? i´m not too sure beacause the dom interpretation wont wait for the images and the 1x1 image gets interpreted when the big images are not loaded yet, and the 1x1 will be very fast loaded, so maybe it fails try it out

Comment: I just did , works well for images but it kinda stumbles on embeds , youtube or vimeo.